# In function there are two return statements and which return statement will execute?

Tags: c, return

```
int main()
{  
   int f=fun();
   ...
}
int fun()
{
   return 1;
   return 2;
}
```

In the above program, when a function is called from the main function and the function contains two return statements,

1. Will both return statements execute? or else
2. If only one return statement executes, why? Then what about another return statement whether executes or not?

Comment: This is well-written and if the OP is graduating from Java, not at all a poor question.

Comment: Look at the [generated assembly code](https://godbolt.org/g/cZP1pC). Obviously the second `return` is optimized away.

Answer (score 6):

Program control **never** reaches `return 2;` and an optimising compiler will remove it.

The only language I know that's insane enough to have two `return` statements that are reached is Java:

```
try {
    return 1; // this is evaluated
} finally {
    return 2; // this is the one actually returned
}
```

Comment: @BartFriederichs: Dunnit.

Comment: Never try to out-insane C. `int func (void) { longjmp(van_halen, 1); return 2; return 3; }`. A function with two return statements that never returns either of them!  :)

Answer (score 0):

If you rember that a **return** statement corresponds to an assembly opcode like **RTS** ("return from sub-routine") that set the value of the Program Counter with the address of the instruction after the call, it will be obviously that the second return statement is never executed.

Comment: When you are speaking of assembly, you should always mention - which architecture you are talking about. The days where the "assembly" defaulted to x86 in 95% of the cases are over a long ago.

Comment: I understand and agree with your tip, but in this case i don't want risk to confuse the author of the question. When i mentioned the RTS i was referring to the MC68000 assembly.